# Lumia 535 asking for WiFi to download WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-535

I have downloaded WhatsApp successful once, but due to some reason I have deleted WhatsApp. After a month when I tried to download WhatsApp again it's asking to connect with WiFi and says it's unable to download with mobile data connection. I want to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two most common issues when updating WhatsApp from the Microsoft Store:

•  If you receive an error code when trying to download WhatsApp, it's from the Microsoft Store and not WhatsApp.

•  If you see "Attention Required" or "Waiting for Wi-Fi" when trying to download WhatsApp, please refer to the settings of the Microsoft Store App. Open Microsoft Store > tap the three horizontal bars in the upper left corner > Settings > App updates and adjust your settings here.

As mentioned [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/28060011/)